# Integral of $\ln(\cosh x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, hyperbolic-functions

$$\int \ln(\cosh x) dx$$

Tried for some time, couldn't get anywhere.

This IS an elementary function, isn't it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the domain of integration? Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset maths here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers! ref: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6348/290189

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+ln(cosh(x))) gives a result involving the polylogarithmic function $\mathrm{Li}_2.$ I don't think that's considered elementary.

Comment: this integral can not expressed by the known elementary functions

Comment: "This IS an elementary function, isn't it?": no. What makes you think that ?

Answer (score 3):

$$\ln(\cosh(x))=\ln\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2\right)=x-\ln(2)+\ln(1+e^{-2x})= x-\ln(2)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{e^{-2kx}}k.$$

You can integrate term-wise and get a rapidly converging series (for positive $x$), which is asymptotic to the parabola $\dfrac{x^2}2-\ln(2)\,x+C$.

Answer (score 3):

The integral $\int \log(\cosh(x))\,dx$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.  To see this, we enforce the substitution $x=\log(u)$ to obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int \log(\cosh(x))\,dx&=\int \frac{\log(1+u^2)-\log(u)}{u}\,du-\log(2)x \\\\
&=\int \frac{\log(1+u^2)}{u}\,du -\frac12 x^2-\log(2)x \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Next, we let $u=\sqrt{v}$ in the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ to reveal

$$\begin{align}
\int \log(\cosh(x))\,dx&=\int \frac{\log(1+v)}{2v}\,dv -\frac12 x^2-\log(2)x \\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{-\frac12\text{Li}_2(-e^{2x})-\frac12x^2-\log(2)x+C}\tag 2
\end{align}$$

which expresses the primitive in terms of the dilogarithm function, a special function given by $\text{Li}_2(x)=-\int_0^x \frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\,dt$.