# Dilogarithm Function on Negative Domain

Tags: integration, polylogarithm

I'm not that good with math, but somehow ended up solving for
$ \int { \ln { (\cosh x) } } \cdot dx $. This has led me to the answer described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182256/integral-of-ln-cosh-x). In my case, I need a solution for x > 1, consequently ending up with a negative input for the spence function.

I was going to use this [npm](https://npm.io/package/@stdlib/math-base-special-spence) package, but the docs explicitly state that the Spence's function is not defined on negative input. However, I found a peculiar identity described in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9408113) (eqn 1.8):

$$
Li_2(z) + Li_2(-z) = \dfrac {1} {2} Li_2(z^2)
$$

My question is, if we have this identity above, wouldn't we able to define dilogarithm function on negative numbers? I have tried a rough plot on desmos with the summation definition: $ \sum_n^{50} {\dfrac {x^n} {n^2}} $, though not perfect it was usable as a good approximation. Is something wrong here, or can the dilogarithm function be defined for negative numbers as well?